# Adding a sequential value using a loop

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe which is effectively combined output from a nested list using `do.call(rbind, nested_list)`

The output has the same number of rows for each list element (e.g. 5 rows per list) and I need to add a column which has a unique numeric code for each list (or group). How can I write a loop to reproduce the group column I have included in the example below, e.g. the five rows have a group value == 1, rows 6 to 10 have a group value == 2, rows 11 to 15 have a group value == 3

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:15)
df$Var_A <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29)
df$Var_B <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16)
df$Var_C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$Var_D <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$New_A <- c(2,5,5,8,11,14,15,17,20,21,22,23,25,25,27)
df$New_B <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16)
df$New_C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$New_D <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$Group <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)

   ID Var_A Var_B Var_C Var_D New_A New_B New_C New_D Group
1   1     1    10    10    10     2    10    10    10     1
2   2     3     0    12    12     5     0    12    12     1
3   3     5     0    14    14     5     0    14    14     1
4   4     7     0    16    16     8     0    16    16     1
5   5     9    12    10    10    11    12    10    10     1
6   6    11    12    12    12    14    12    12    12     2
7   7    13    12    14    14    15    12    14    14     2
8   8    15    12    16    16    17    12    16    16     2
9   9    17     0    10    10    20     0    10    10     2
10 10    19    14    12    12    21    14    12    12     2
11 11    21    NA    14    14    22    NA    14    14     3
12 12    23    14    16    16    23    14    16    16     3
13 13    25    16    10    10    25    16    10    10     3
14 14    27    16    12    12    25    16    12    12     3
15 15    29    16    14    14    27    16    14    14     3
```

Comment: Do you mean `df$Group <- rep(1:3, each = 5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `dplyr::mutate` with `dplyr::row_number`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   mutate(Group=ceiling(row_number() / 5))
```

Output:

```
   ID Var_A Var_B Var_C Var_D New_A New_B New_C New_D Group
1   1     1    10    10    10     2    10    10    10     1
2   2     3     0    12    12     5     0    12    12     1
3   3     5     0    14    14     5     0    14    14     1
4   4     7     0    16    16     8     0    16    16     1
5   5     9    12    10    10    11    12    10    10     1
6   6    11    12    12    12    14    12    12    12     2
7   7    13    12    14    14    15    12    14    14     2
8   8    15    12    16    16    17    12    16    16     2
9   9    17     0    10    10    20     0    10    10     2
10 10    19    14    12    12    21    14    12    12     2
11 11    21    NA    14    14    22    NA    14    14     3
12 12    23    14    16    16    23    14    16    16     3
13 13    25    16    10    10    25    16    10    10     3
14 14    27    16    12    12    25    16    12    12     3
15 15    29    16    14    14    27    16    14    14     3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ceiling` function:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:15)
df$Var_A <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29)
df$Var_B <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16)
df$Var_C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$Var_D <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$New_A <- c(2,5,5,8,11,14,15,17,20,21,22,23,25,25,27)
df$New_B <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16)
df$New_C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$New_D <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14)
df$Group <- ceiling(as.numeric(df$ID)/5)

df
#    ID Var_A Var_B Var_C Var_D New_A New_B New_C New_D Group
# 1   1     1    10    10    10     2    10    10    10     1
# 2   2     3     0    12    12     5     0    12    12     1
# 3   3     5     0    14    14     5     0    14    14     1
# 4   4     7     0    16    16     8     0    16    16     1
# 5   5     9    12    10    10    11    12    10    10     1
# 6   6    11    12    12    12    14    12    12    12     2
# 7   7    13    12    14    14    15    12    14    14     2
# 8   8    15    12    16    16    17    12    16    16     2
# 9   9    17     0    10    10    20     0    10    10     2
# 10 10    19    14    12    12    21    14    12    12     2
# 11 11    21    NA    14    14    22    NA    14    14     3
# 12 12    23    14    16    16    23    14    16    16     3
# 13 13    25    16    10    10    25    16    10    10     3
# 14 14    27    16    12    12    25    16    12    12     3
# 15 15    29    16    14    14    27    16    14    14     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Without adding an ID or rownums we can do this using nrow and knowledge of the group length.

```
group_len <- 5
groups <- nrow(df)/group_len
df$group <- rep(1:groups, each = group_len)

# Example: 
# rep(1:3, each = 5)
# 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to combine `cumsum` with `rep`.

```
cumsum(rep_len(c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 4)), nrow(df)))
#cumsum(rep_len(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), nrow(df))) #Alternative
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

Or making use of auto repeat.

```
df$Group <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 4))
df$Group <- cumsum(df$Group)
df$Group
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

Or create a sequence with length of `nrow` and make an integer division `%/%`.

```
0:(nrow(df)-1) %/% 5
#seq(0, nrow(df)-1) %/% 5    #Alternative
#(seq_len(nrow(df))-1) %/% 5 #Alternative
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

Or using `rep`:

```
rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df)/5), each=5, length.out=nrow(df))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `cut` function with `labels = FALSE` to return an integer to use for the group.

```
n_per_group <- 5
df$group <- cut(x = df$ID, breaks = nrow(df) / n_per_group, labels = FALSE)
df$group 
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```